# How can I join 2 tables when joining a column with a string from another column?

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

```
Table a
id   |    title
12   |    category1


Table b
id   |    link
45   |    index.php&view=myview&id=12
```

How can I join the tables where a.id = (the id inside the b.link)

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN b
   ON a.id = LEFT(REVERSE(b.link),LOCATE('=',REVERSE(b.link))-1)
```

1. [REVERSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) b.link
2. Find the first occurence of '=' ([LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)) on the reversed b.link
3. Extract the [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) part of the reversed b.link from 0 to position of first occurence of '=' minus 1

you can also use RIGHT that way:

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN b
   ON a.id = RIGHT(b.link,LOCATE('=',REVERSE(b.link))-1)
```

the second option use one function less then should be faster than the first

This is not tested but if your links have all the same pattern it should work

Comment: W000 this is a fancy solution i like this :) I would suggest adding a column but this sure is the solution if that's not an option!

Comment: this sounds promising. I'll check this out

Answer (score 1):

Your best method would be to add an extra column to table b and add the id via a server side script when the record is initially added. It will make your sql much quicker

Comment: I'm going to guess that the tables are not changeable. @yann, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
Table a
id   |    title
12   |    category1


Table b
id   |    link                          | a_id
45   |    index.php&view=myview&id=12   | 12
```

Query:

```
Select * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id WHERE a.id = 12
```